# My Armature Bends in a weird way

Tags: armature, bones

[Link to blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/04c6217da0d846cd9fa3da28d95c5401)

Whenever I try to  move my armature it bends weirdly. I set all the vertexes I wanted onto the bone and I can't find a way to fix it. I feel like its something stupid simple that I'm missing. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: ok sure I did it

Answer (score 0):

Apply the scale and rotation of both the character and armature, parent again and it will work fine

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing it right but when I apply rotation and scale to both and reparent Its doing the same thing as last time.

Comment: mmh that's weird, I've tried again and it works fine

Comment: It only works when the upper arm bone isn't set to a group